# Speed/Performance difference between `wp_ajax` and `init` checks for AJAX/POST requests?

Tags: ajax

Typically, people do ajax calls like:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ACTIONNAME',   [$this, 'callback_Function'] );
```

However, I am interested, what are key differences (other than having authorization checks & `wp_ajax_nopriv_` ) from doing the AJAX `$_POST` checks within:

```
add_action( 'init', [$this, 'callback_Function'], 1 );   // I know, priority with 10 might make it slower

public function callback_Function()
{
    if(!empty($_POST['action']=="ACTIONNAME"))
        ....
}
```

my main interest here is if there is any significant speed/performance difference?

Comment: Well, I tested on a default WordPress install (just one small Must Use plugin for running the tests, no other plugins and using the default theme) and there was almost no difference in the time that was taken to load the page up until my custom `init`/`wp_ajax_` action, or that sometimes the `init` takes 0.01 - 0.03 second(s) *less* than the `wp_ajax_` and sometimes it's vice-versa. But on another site with plugins like WooCommerce, when I changed the `init`'s priority from `1` to `11`, the `init` action time was always greater than the `wp_ajax_` time.

Comment: So I think it all depends on the active plugins and theme(s) used on the site - i.e. how many options auto-loaded, how small/big each option is, how well the server itself is, how well/performant one's code is, etc. I.e. If you want to measure the performance, check those things instead of comparing `init` etc. vs `wp_ajax_`. And btw, on the best practice side, using the `wp_ajax_` hook is the proper way to run AJAX actions in WordPress, but nowadays, a better (predictable & structured as the [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) says) way would be using the REST API. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ you can convert that to answer, i will definitely upvote!